# Validation error value is not valid

Tags: jsf, jpa, primefaces

I know this is a common error, and that there is a lots of questions about it, but I must create new one.

Here is my jsf page:

```
<h:form id="clientCreatingForm">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{kkmBean.client.address.city}" style="width: 263px;" 
          converter="cityConveter" required="true" requiredMessage="You must choose one city">
          <f:selectItems value="#{kkmBean.cityList}" var="city" itemLabel="#{city.cityName}" itemValue="#{city.cityID}"/>
     </p:selectOneMenu>


     <p:commandButton value="Save client" type="button" onclick="confirm.show()" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 30px; width: 180px;" />
     <p:commandButton value="Reset fields" type="reset" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 30px; width: 180px;"/>

          <p:confirmDialog message="Are you sure, you want to save client?" 
               header="Save client" severity="info" widgetVar="confirm">

               <p:commandButton value="Yes, I am sure." oncomplete="confirm.hide()" 
                                         action="#{kkmBean.saveClient}" update=":warnings" style="font-size: 12px;"/>
               <p:commandButton value="No, I don't!" onclick="confirm.hide()" type="button" style="font-size: 12px;"/>
          </p:confirmDialog>
</h:form>
```

Here is managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "kkmBean")
@SessionScoped
public class CreatingClientManager implements Serializable {

/** Creates a new instance of CreatingClientManager */
public KreiranjeKorisnikaManager() {
    client= new Client();
    client.setAddress(new Address());
    cityList = new LinkedList<City>();
    cityList = Communication.getInstance().getCitySessionBeanRemote().getCities();
  }

private Client client;
private List<City> cityList;

public String startCreatingClent() {

    return "creating-client";
  }

/**
 * @return the client
 */
public Klijent getClient() {
    return client;
  }

/**
 * @param client the client to set
 */
public void setClient(Client client) {
    this.Client = client;
  }

/**
 * @return the cityList
 */
public List<Grad> getCityList() {
    return cityList;
  }

/**
 * @param cityList the cityList to set
 */
public void setCityList(List<City> cityList) {
    this.cityList = cityList;
  }

public String saveClient() {
    System.out.println("i am in saveClient method");
    String message = Communication.getInstance().getClientSessionBeanRemote.saveClient(client);
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    kontekst.addMessage(message, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Success: ", message));
    return null;
  }
}
```

And finally converter:

```
   @FacesConverter(forClass=City.class, value="cityConverter")
   public class CityConverter implements Converter {

   @Override
   public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
      Integer cityID = Integer.valueOf(value);
      CreatingClientManager kkm = (CreatingClientManager) ((HttpSession)context.getExternalContext().getSession(true)).getAttribute("kkmBean");
      List<Grad> cityList = kkm.getCityList();
      for (int i = 0; i < cityList.size(); i++) {
          City city = cityList.get(i);
          if(city.getCityID().equals(cityID)) {
              System.out.println(city.getCityName());
              return city;
          }
      }
      return null;
  }

  @Override
  public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
      return value.toString();
  }
}
```

Of course the problem is in selectOneMenu. When I submit form, i got this annoying error.

I was debugging converter and the line before return grad, i print grad.getImeGrada() and everything is fine, the name (Ime) of found city (grad) is printed. Am I missing something?

p.s. Sorry on my English, I hope that you understand what is my problem.

Almost forgot to mention that i override equals and hashCode methods, and i am sure it is ok.

Comment: Programming in English instead of Bosnian or an arbitrary non-English language would make the code much quickier interpretable to the worldwide audience... After reading the code 3 times I gave up (but I could conclude that the `Converter` is bad). At least, the `Validation error: Value not valid` on a `<h:selectOneMenu>` simply means that the selected value doesn't match any of the available items in the list. Perhaps the `equals()` method of your `Grad` class is broken. This very same kind of answer has been posted in a zillion of questions already.

Comment: @BalusC thank you on your effort.

I hope that my code is easier to understand now, when i "translated" it.

Comment: Much appreciated :) I see the problem. I'll post an answer.

Comment: Here is equals method:
`@Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof City)) {
            return false;
        }
        City other = (City) object;
        if ((this.cityID == null && other.cityID != null) || (this.cityID != null && !this.cityID.equals(other.cityID))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
`
Hope you will handle with code written like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way how you specified the `itemValue` of `<f:selectItems>` and implemented the `getAsString()` of the converter is not right.

When the selected value is submitted, JSF will convert the `cityID` to `City` by `getAsObject()` of the converter. Then, JSF will validate the `City` against the `itemValue` of the `<f:selectItems>` to see if it is really part of the list (this is to avoid hackers which modifies/tampers requests with a different value). However, since `itemValue` is `cityID` which is an `Integer` the comparison fails for every item of the list. Hence the `Value not valid` error.

You need to change `itemValue` to be `City` instead and change `getAsString()` to return the `cityID`:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{kkmBean.client.address.city}" style="width: 263px;" 
      converter="cityConveter" required="true" requiredMessage="You must choose one city">
      <f:selectItems value="#{kkmBean.cityList}" var="city" itemLabel="#{city.cityName}" itemValue="#{city}"/>
 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

and

```
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    City city = (City) value;
    return city.getCityID() != null ? String.valueOf(city.getCityID()) : null;
}
```

Summarized: the type of the `itemValue` must be **exactly the same** as the type of the dropdown `value` and the converter must convert between exactly that type and string.

#### See also:

- [Validation Error: Value is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069379/validation-error-value-is-not-valid/9069660#9069660)

Comment: Words can not describe how grateful I am to you. I am beginner in jsf, but I didn't expect that problem like this will take two days to me, and you solve it in few minutes. Once more, thank you very, very much.

Comment: @BalusC : I am getting error as `java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.sac.beans` because in `Object getAsObject`, `value` is STRING. How to overcome this?

Comment: @BalusC : Can you take a look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874394/targetcars-validation-error-value-is-not-valid)