# How to create a picklist in JSF? Tried moving items using JS/jQuery, but submit errors with "Validation Error: Value is not valid"

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, listbox, multi-select

I am creating web application using JSF 2.0 where I am assigning users to view projects. For that I have two list. First list that have users who are not assigned that project and list B have users who have assigned that project. And we can interchange the data.

Code I have is

---

```
<t:selectManyListbox id="sourceCars"  style="width: 40%;"
                     value="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.listOfUsers}" size="10">
    <t:selectItems value="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.showAllMyRemData()}" var="t"
                   itemLabel="#{t.title}" itemValue="#{t.status}"/>
</t:selectManyListbox>

<span>
    <input type="button" value=" >> " id="dbleMeRight"/>
    <input type="button" value=" &lt;&lt; " id="dbleMeLeft"/>
</span>

<t:selectManyListbox id="targetCars"  style="width: 40%;"
                     value="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.listOfUsers}" size="10">
    <t:selectItems value="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.showAllMyData()}" var="n"
                   itemLabel="#{n.title}" itemValue="#{n.status}"/>
</t:selectManyListbox>

<h:commandButton value="Save Edited Project Info." action="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.editPatentData(MyLogin.loginname)}" />
```

where t is `xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"`.

---

**PersonalInformationDataBean.java**

```
private List<String> listOfUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> listOfUsers002 = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<CommonBean01> listOfListUsers = new ArrayList<CommonBean01>();
private List<CommonBean01> listOfListUsers002 = new ArrayList<CommonBean01>();

// above getter and setters

Iterator itr = listOfUsers.iterator();
System.out.println("list of usersssss == " + listOfUsers);

while (itr.hasNext()) {
    psmtt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO patentInvite (invitedWhom, patentId, personalInfoId) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    String inviteWhom = itr.next().toString();
    System.out.println("to who we have invited is " + inviteWhom);
    psmtt.setString(1, inviteWhom);
    psmtt.setLong(2, patentId);
    psmtt.setLong(3, personalInfoId);
    psmtt.execute();

    System.out.println("Data entered is == " + inviteWhom + "==" + patentId + "==" + personalInfoId + "==");
}

public List<CommonBean01> showAllMyRemData() {
    try {
        CommonBean01 commonBean = new CommonBean01();
        listOfListUsers = new ArrayList<CommonBean01>();
        ConnectToDatabase db = new ConnectToDatabase();
        Connection conn = db.makeconnection();


        PreparedStatement psmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM patentInvite WHERE patentId=?");
        System.out.println("patent id here is " + patentId);
        psmt.setLong(1, patentId);
        ResultSet rs = psmt.executeQuery(), rs2 = null;
        PreparedStatement pstt = null;

        int dd = 0;
        String listOfUser = "";
        int myCounter = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            if (myCounter==0) {
                listOfUser = "'" + rs.getString(2) + "'"; 
            } else {
                listOfUser = listOfUser + ",'" + rs.getString(2) + "'";
            }
            myCounter++;
        }

        System.out.println("id selected are :: " + listOfUser);

        psmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT userid, fullName, userType FROM userDetails WHERE userid NOT IN (" + listOfUser + ")");
        rs = psmt.executeQuery();

        listOfListUsers = new ArrayList<CommonBean01>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            commonBean = new CommonBean01();
            commonBean.setStatus(rs.getString(1));
            commonBean.setTitle(rs.getString(2) + " [" + rs.getString(3) + "]");
            listOfListUsers.add(commonBean);
            System.out.println("wat say....(" + rs.getString(1) + ") -- " + rs.getString(2) + "");
        }
        return listOfListUsers;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception = " + e);
        return null;
    }
}

public List<CommonBean01> showAllMyData() {
    try {
        CommonBean01 commonBean = new CommonBean01();
        listOfListUsers = new ArrayList<CommonBean01>();
        ConnectToDatabase db = new ConnectToDatabase();
        Connection conn = db.makeconnection();

        PreparedStatement psmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM patentInvite WHERE patentId=?");
        System.out.println("patent id here is " + patentId);
        psmt.setLong(1, patentId);
        ResultSet rs = psmt.executeQuery(), rs2 = null;
        PreparedStatement pstt = null;
        listOfListUsers = new ArrayList<CommonBean01>();

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("");
            pstt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT userid, fullName, userType FROM userDetails WHERE userid=?");
            pstt.setString(1, rs.getString(2));
            System.out.println("setting id for " + rs.getString(1));
            rs2 = pstt.executeQuery();

            int dd = 0;
            while (rs2.next()) {
                System.out.println("inside data " + rs2.getString(2));
                commonBean = new CommonBean01();
                commonBean.setStatus(rs2.getString(1));
                commonBean.setTitle(rs2.getString(2) + " [" + rs2.getString(3) + "]");
                listOfListUsers.add(commonBean);
                System.out.println("wat say here....(" + rs2.getString(1) + ") -- " + rs2.getString(2) + "");
            }
        }
        return listOfListUsers;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception = " + e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

**CommonBean01.java**

```
public class CommonBean01 {
    private String title;
    private String status;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final CommonBean01 other = (CommonBean01) obj;
        if ((this.status == null) ? (other.status != null) : !this.status.equals(other.status)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 89 * hash + (this.status != null ? this.status.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }
}
```

---

Now when I take user from left list to right list and click `Save Edit Info` button, I get error as `targetCars: Validation Error: Value is not valid`.

**Note :**

When I don't change any list and click `Save Edit Info`, it works well.

Any idea why I am getting this error?

---

### Edit 1

I made below changes

```
<t:selectManyListbox id="sourceCars"  style="width: 40%;"
                     value="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.listOfUsers002}" size="10">
    <t:selectItems value="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.showAllMyRemData()}" var="t"
                   itemLabel="#{t.title}" itemValue="#{t.status}"/>
</t:selectManyListbox>


public List<CommonBean01> showAllMyRemData() {
    try {
        CommonBean01 commonBean = new CommonBean01();
        listOfListUsers002 = new ArrayList<CommonBean01>();
        ConnectToDatabase db = new ConnectToDatabase();
        Connection conn = db.makeconnection();


        PreparedStatement psmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM patentInvite WHERE patentId=?");
        System.out.println("patent id here is " + patentId);
        psmt.setLong(1, patentId);
        ResultSet rs = psmt.executeQuery(), rs2 = null;
        PreparedStatement pstt = null;

        int dd = 0;
        String listOfUser = "";
        int myCounter = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            if (myCounter==0) {
                listOfUser = "'" + rs.getString(2) + "'"; 
            } else {
                listOfUser = listOfUser + ",'" + rs.getString(2) + "'";
            }
            myCounter++;
        }

        System.out.println("id selected are :: " + listOfUser);

        psmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT userid, fullName, userType FROM userDetails WHERE userid NOT IN (" + listOfUser + ")");
        rs = psmt.executeQuery();

        listOfListUsers002 = new ArrayList<CommonBean01>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            commonBean = new CommonBean01();
            commonBean.setStatus(rs.getString(1));
            commonBean.setTitle(rs.getString(2) + " [" + rs.getString(3) + "]");
            listOfListUsers002.add(commonBean);
            System.out.println("wat say....(" + rs.getString(1) + ") -- " + rs.getString(2) + "");
        }
        return listOfListUsers002;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception = " + e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

still I am getting same error.

---

### Edit 2

jQuery code to move items are as below.

```
$(function() {
    var  sourceCars=$('#sourceCars option').clone();
    $('#filterDis').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        alert("changed me=="+val+"==");
        $('#sourceCars').empty();
        alert("changed me=="+sourceCars+"==");
        sourceCars.filter(function(idx, el) {
            var found=false;
            $('#targetCars option').each(function(){
                if ($(this).val()===$(el).text())
                    found=true;
            });
            alert(found);

            if(found)
                return false;

            return val === 'ALL' || $(el).text().indexOf('[' + val + ']') >= 0;
        }).appendTo('#sourceCars');
        $("#targetCars option").attr("selected", "selected");
    });

    $('#sourceCars').dblclick(function() {
        $('#sourceCars option:selected').appendTo('#targetCars');
        $("#targetCars option").attr("selected", "selected");
    });

    $('#dbleMeRight').click(function() {
        $('#sourceCars option:selected').appendTo('#targetCars');
        $("#targetCars option").attr("selected", "selected");
    });

    $('#targetCars').dblclick(function() {

        var targetList=$('#targetCars option:selected');
        var filterVal= $('#filterDis').val();
        if( filterVal === 'ALL' || targetList.text().indexOf('[' + filterVal + ']') >= 0)
            targetList.appendTo('#sourceCars');
        else
            targetList.remove();
        var foption = $('#sourceCars option:first');
        var soptions = $.makeArray($('#sourceCars option:not(:first)')).sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text &lt; b.text ? -1 : 1
        });
        $('#sourceCars').html(soptions).prepend(foption);
        foption.attr("selected", true).siblings("option").removeAttr("selected");
        $("#targetCars option").attr("selected", "selected");
    });

    $('#dbleMeLeft').click(function() {

        var targetList=$('#targetCars option:selected');
        var filterVal= $('#filterDis').val();
        if( filterVal === 'ALL' || targetList.text().indexOf('[' + filterVal + ']') >= 0)
            targetList.appendTo('#sourceCars');
        else
            targetList.remove();
        var foption = $('#sourceCars option:first');
        var soptions = $.makeArray($('#sourceCars option:not(:first)')).sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text &lt; b.text ? -1 : 1
        });
        $('#sourceCars').html(soptions).prepend(foption);
        foption.attr("selected", true).siblings("option").removeAttr("selected");
        $("#targetCars option").attr("selected", "selected");
    });

});
```

***NOTE: If I move item from List B (Right) to List A (left), it works fine. BUT WHEN I move item from List A (Left) to List B (right), I get this error.***

---

Comment: what code you have written on click of left/right button? issue seems to be there, paste that piece of code here to help you.

Comment: that is a jquery code. I will paste the same... I don't think that is problem as if I remove from list B to A it works. But if I put any item from A to B, I get error

Comment: You have a conversion error. In JSF, when you're using lists of custom objects to populate any of the `selecItem` type UI components, you need to implement a custom `converter` that will help JSF make sense of the submission. I wish I could give more help, but as it is, your code is difficult to read. Unrelated to the question, please try alternative naming convention for your variables. It's difficult to make sense of `ttt` and `ttt2` and stuff like that. A tutorial on converters [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/). For primitve/standard java types, no need.

Comment: @kolossus : I have made changes in code now... Please let me know for changes.

Comment: take a look at this picklist : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/picklist.jsf

Comment: @Daniel : Thanks I will take a look at this too... This is what actually I was looking for... because I also needed to filter the left list based on the group text I have in name e.g. Name 1 (G1), Name 2 (G1), Name 3 (G2)...

Comment: @Daniel : From where I will get `import org.primefaces.examples.domain.Player;` file? Because I am getting error as "File is not present in this component"

Comment: from google :) http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/examples/trunk/showcase/src/main/java/org/primefaces/examples/domain/Player.java?r=3692 , when you need some java file of primefaces just search for it using google , its all there...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the point, your concrete problem is caused by the mistake that you filled listbox items using JavaScript/jQuery instead of JSF. This way JSF is never been made aware of the new items added by JavaScript. You need to fill the listbox items using JSF instead of JavaScript/jQuery.

When you submit a form with an `UISelectOne`/`UISelectMany` component, then JSF will always compare the submitted value to the list of available items from `<f:selectItem(s)>`. If the submitted value is not contained in the list of available items, then you will get exactly this `Validation Error: Value is not valid` error. This is part of builtin safeguard against tampered/attacked requests. The client should not be able to submit a item which the server has not specified.

Changing the available items in JavaScript/jQuery side does *not* automagically also change the available items in JSF `<f:selectItems>` side as well. You really need to change the available items in JSF side. You can easily use the JSF 2.x ajax powers for this. Here's a concrete kickoff example:

```html
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <h:selectManyListbox id="left" value="#{bean.leftSelected}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{bean.leftAvailable}" />
            <f:ajax event="dblclick" render="left right" listener="#{bean.leftToRight}" />
        </h:selectManyListbox>
        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:commandButton value="left to right">
                <f:ajax execute="left" render="left right" listener="#{bean.leftToRight}" />
            </h:commandButton>
            <br/>
            <h:commandButton value="right to left">
                <f:ajax execute="right" render="left right" listener="#{bean.rightToLeft}" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:selectManyListbox id="right" value="#{bean.rightSelected}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{bean.rightAvailable}" />
            <f:ajax event="dblclick" render="left right" listener="#{bean.rightToLeft}" />
        </h:selectManyListbox>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

with

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private List<String> leftSelected;
    private List<String> leftAvailable;
    private List<String> rightSelected;
    private List<String> rightAvailable;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        leftAvailable = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five"));
        rightAvailable = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void leftToRight() {
        leftAvailable.removeAll(leftSelected);
        rightAvailable.addAll(leftSelected);
        leftSelected = null;
    }

    public void rightToLeft() {
        rightAvailable.removeAll(rightSelected);
        leftAvailable.addAll(rightSelected);
        rightSelected = null;
    }

    // Add/generate getters+setters. Note: the "available" lists doesn't need setters.
}
```

That's all. No JS/jQuery mess necessary. When using custom non-string objects don't forget to provide a proper converter and `equals()` method.

#### See also:

- [What is the need of JSF, when UI can be achieved with JavaScript libraries such as jQuery and AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421839/what-is-the-need-of-jsf-when-ui-can-be-achieved-from-css-html-javascript-jquery/4424775#4424775)
- [Validation Error: Value is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069379/validation-error-value-is-not-valid)
- [Conversion Error setting value for 'null Converter' - Why do I need a Converter in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734580/conversion-error-setting-value-for-null-converter-why-do-i-need-a-converter)

Comment: I have object in list... so I added `<f:selectItems value="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.listOfListUsers002}" var="leftSide" itemLabel="#{leftSide.title}" itemValue="#{leftSide}"/>`. All array list type is `private List<CommonBean02> listOfUsers = new ArrayList<CommonBean02>();`. When I try to move, it gives me popup as `serverError: class java.lang.ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.sac.beans.CommonBean02`

Comment: Your converter is missing or broken. This problem is unrelated to the concrete question. The code in the answer works as-is. For an example, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734580/jsf-2-selection-combo-box-with-without-conversion-strategy/4735322#4735322

Comment: on this I am working tomorrow as had to finish some things of another project... will get back to you tomorrow incase of any problem...

Comment: Could you please take a look at my new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999353/images-wont-load-if-they-are-of-high-size)