# how to call Java method after double clicking value of listbox

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, listbox, multi-select, double-click

I have multi-select listbox as below.

```
<t:selectManyListbox id="sourceCars"  style="width: 40%;"
                     value="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.listOfUsers002}" size="10">
    <t:selectItems value="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.showAllMyRemData()}" var="t"
                   itemLabel="#{t.title}" itemValue="#{t.status}" >
    </t:selectItems>
</t:selectManyListbox>
```

What I want is call a Java method say `callMeOnDoubleClick()` if I double click the item in the listbox.

Any idea how to get this done?

Comment: Perhaps with an Asynchronous call when you click on that. You could use a Ajax function to do this, or a Jquery call but probably the famework you are using(JSF i suppose) has already a feature to do this.

Comment: @PbxMan : Which feature?

Comment: @FahimParkar Don't you want to use the `valueChangeListener` ? of `t:selectManyListbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<f:ajax event="dblclick">`.

```
<t:selectManyListbox ...>
    <f:ajax event="dblclick" listener="#{bean.listener}" />
</t:selectManyListbox>
```

#### See also:

- [How to create a picklist in JSF? Tried moving items using JS/jQuery, but submit errors with "Validation Error: Value is not valid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874394/how-to-create-a-picklist-in-jsf-tried-moving-items-using-js-jquery-but-submit)

Comment: could you please take a look at my new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999353/images-wont-load-if-they-are-of-high-size)