# Images won't load if they are of high size

Tags: java, mysql, image, jsf, servlets

I am storing images in DB using MEDIUMBLOB. When I try to load image through a servlet, I am able to see those images. However if the image size is big (1 MB or more), I can see half or 3/4th image on the browser.

When I download same image and put it in public webcontent, it works perfectly. Any idea how to overcome this issue? Do I need to set any variable in the servlet or MySQL?

The (JSF-generated) HTML code is as follows:

```
<img src="DisplayImage?mainID=drawing" />
```

The image servlet does the following:

```
String imgLen = rs1.getString(1);
int len = imgLen.length();
byte[] rb = new byte[len];
InputStream readImg = rs1.getBinaryStream(1);
InputStream inputStream = readImg;
int index = readImg.read(rb, 0, len);
response.reset();
response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(len));
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename=/file.png");
response.setContentType("image/png");
response.getOutputStream().write(rb, 0, len);
response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

### Edit 1

When I use below code and save file to local disk, I see full Image.

```
String imgLen = rs1.getString(1);
int len = imgLen.length();
rb = new byte[len];
inputStream = rs1.getBinaryStream(1);
while ((read = inputStream.read(rb)) != -1) {
    out.write(rb, 0, read);
}
out.flush();
out.close();
```

### Edit 2

When I save the half viewed images I noticed that the size of those **images are 100KB**. My 1 MB image is showing size as 100KB. This is happening with all images :(

I think this is biggest HINT what wrong is going on. BUT I am not getting what is wrong.

### Edit 3

If I remove below stuff from my `web.xml`, I am able to view those images.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Can I remove those? I don't re-collect why exactly I added those...

### Edit 4

My web.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            60
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>restrict</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.sac.filter.MyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>restrict</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DisplayImage</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sac.databean.DisplayImage</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DisplayImage</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/DisplayImage</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SaveMyImage</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sac.databean.SaveMyImage</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SaveMyImage</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SaveMyImage</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: how do you retrieve the images from db? Are you using any component library such as primefaces?

Comment: @berkay : Using `getBinaryStream`

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSF. You'd have exactly the same problem when using plain HTML `<img>`. This has anything to do with whatever is sitting behind `DisplayImage` URL. You'd need to focus on its code.

Comment: As per your code update, `String#length()` returns the amount of characters in the string. Does it really represent the image's length?

Comment: @BalusC : yes... if images are small, they are getting displayed...

Comment: @BalusC : When I save the images that are displayed on browser, there size is 100 KB. I tried with 4 images and all are 100 KB size. That means something is going fishy....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way how you measured the image's length is wrong. You're basically converting the image bytes to human readable characters (in an unintelligible sequence, but that aside) and then calculating the amount of characters. This is not right. You need to calculate the amount of raw and unconverted bytes instead. One character is not necessarily represented by only one byte, but it can be represented by more than one byte.

There are 2 ways to solve your problem:

1. Use `ResultSet#getBytes()` instead.

   ```
   byte[] content = resultSet.getBytes("content");
   // ...
   response.setContentLength(content.length);
   response.getOutputStream().write(content);
   ```

   Please note that this is memory hogging as every `byte` of a `byte[]` basically accumulates one byte of Java's memory.
2. Select the BLOB length in the query as well. How to do that depends on the DB used. In MySQL, you can use the `LENGTH()` function for this.

   ```
   SELECT content, LENGTH(content) AS contentLength FROM image WHERE id = ?
   ```

   Which you then process as follows:

   ```
   InputStream content = resultSet.getBinaryStream("content");
   int contentLength = resultSet.getInt("contentLength");
   // ...
   response.setContentLength(contentLength);
   SomeUtil.streamByBuffer(content, response.getOutputStream());
   ```

   *(wherein the process is not taken place through a `byte[]` of full image's length)*

---

**Update**: after all, the request on the image seemed to have invoked the `MyFacesExtensionsFilter` which is apparently overzealously buffering the response without properly flushing it when the `chain.doFilter()` returns. This filter is according the mapping rules only invoked when the `FacesServlet` is invoked. But this shouldn't have happened. The image request should only have invoked the image servlet, not also the faces servlet.

According the mapping rules, the `FacesServlet` is invoked on `/faces/*` while your image servlet is mapped on `/DisplayImage`. The `<img src>` as you've there is relative to the current request URL, so it ultimately ends up to be `/faces/DisplayImage` which will first invoke the `FacesServlet` and then the `DisplayImage` servlet. This is wrong.

You should change the JSF code accordingly so that the `<img src>` ultimately becomes domain-relative so that it invokes only the `/DisplayImage` servlet.

```
<img src="/contextpath/DisplayImage?mainID=drawing" />
```

You can achieve this by just using the leading slash in `<h:graphicImage>`. It will auto-prepend the context path.

```
<h:graphicImage value="/DisplayImage?mainID=drawing" />
```

Comment: `LENGTH(content)` also gives me same number as what I have in `int len = imgLen.length();`

Comment: Well, you have at least eliminated a possible disturbance. What if you replace `response.getOutputStream()` by `new FileOutputStream()`? (so that we can eliminate some other possible causes of the problem)

Comment: (yes, just write to local disk file system and then open with some image viewer)

Comment: This shouldn't matter, but try `close()` after `flush()`. If that fixes the problem, please tell what servletcontainer make/version you're using.

Comment: taking close() after flush() doesn't solve problem... I have servlet code as `public class DisplayImage extends HttpServlet { 
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
`

Comment: When I save the images that are displayed on browser, there size is 100 KB. I tried with 4 images and all are 100 KB size. That means something is going fishy....

Comment: Do you have any filters in your webapp, if so which ones and what do they?

Comment: I just have this in web-xml...     <filter>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

Comment: also this....    <filter>
        <filter-name>restrict</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.sac.filter.MyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

Comment: please see my edit 3, if I remove `MyFacesExtensionsFilter`, I am able to view those images. Yippeee, but not sure, why I added that. I believe I had added those for some reason...

Comment: I wouldn't have expected that. That filter is used by Tomahawk. It's required by `<t:inputFileUpload>` in order to properly process the `multipart/form-data` request and also by a few other components which require specific CSS/JS resources (such as `<t:calendar>`). On which URL patterns is your `FacesServlet` been mapped? The image servlet shouldn't match any one of those. The `MyFacesExtensionsFilter` shouldn't have been invoked when the image servlet is requested.

Comment: I believe `    <filter>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>` means they are invoked on all pages... How to restrict this filter from invoking when servlet is request?

Comment: I have added my web.xml file above... Please let me know if you need any further info...

Comment: According to the mappings in your `web.xml`, the `MyFacesExtensionsFilter` is invoked when the `FacesServlet` is invoked. The `FacesServlet` is invoked when the URL pattern matches `/faces/*`. But your image servlet is mapped on `/DisplayImage`, so it surely doesn't match `/faces/*`. Don't you have any other mappings on the `FacesServlet`? Or is the image ultimately been requested by `/faces/DisplayImage`? (this would however contradict the Servlet API mapping rules)

Comment: Using `<h:graphicImage value="/DisplayImage?mainID=drawing" />` (note the leading slash) should generate the proper URL.

Comment: I tried with `<h:graphicImage value="DisplayImage?mainID=pdfmsoffice&amp;id=pdf&amp;what=cv12"  width="200" height="200" />`, still same problem.

Comment: wow... wow... wow.... problem solved... leading slash makes you and me WINNER :) :) :) :)

Comment: one more problem I am facing. When I have `background-image: url(DisplayImage?mainID=pdfmsoffice&amp;id=pdf&amp;what=cv12)`, I see half Image. when I change to `background-image: url(/DisplayImage?mainID=pdfmsoffice&amp;id=pdf&amp;what=cv12)` I don't see image... all is white background :(

Comment: You should use `url(#{request.contextPath}/DisplayImage?query)` or `url(../DisplayImage?query)`

Comment: actually code I have is `style="#{patentInfo.cvTypeFile.contains('application')?'visibility:visible;width:200px;height:200px;background-image: url(/DisplayImage?mainID=pdfmsoffice&amp;id='.concat(patentInfo.cvType).concat('&amp;what=cv').concat(patentInfo.personalInfoId).concat(');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%;background-color:transparent;border:0px'):'visibility:hidden;width:1px;height:1px;'}"`.

Comment: and above gives which gives me HTML output code as `style="visibility:visible;width:200px;height:200px;background-image: url(DisplayImage?mainID=pdfmsoffice&amp;id=pdf&amp;what=cv12);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%;background-color:transparent;border:0px"`

Comment: working like a charm.... thanks Boss :) you saved me and LEARNED this as a new chapter. I never faces this problem before as we always try with smaller images.